# Button function OpenInNewTab not working once inside <figcaption>

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I have a button that when clicked opens a new tab with a URL stated in the javascript. However, once I put this button inside a figcaption it's clickable, but the javascript doesn't work. Here's the code:

```
<div class="container-top-pics">
      <div class="row-top-pics">
        <div class="column-left-pic">
          <div class="col-inner">
            <img src="Images/sf-downtown.jpg">
              <figcaption>
                WELCOME TO THE<br />
                  <h1>DEAL GUIDE</h1><br />
              </figcaption> 
          </div>
        </div> 
          <div class="column-right-pic">
            <div class="col-inner">
              <img src="Images/sf-ad.jpg">
              <figcaption>
                SPECIAL DEALS<br />
                <h1>GET THEM</h1>
                <h2>NOW</h2>
                <button type="button" id="button-ad" class="button-ad" onclick="OpenInNewTab()">RESERVE NOW</button>
                </figcaption>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

CSS:

```
.container-top-pics {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width:1140px;
}

img {
    max-width:100%;
}

.column-right-pic {
    float:left;
    width:29%;
    position: relative;
}

.column-right-pic figcaption {
    font-family: "Avenir";
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 1vw;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  line-height: 5em;
}
.column-right-pic h1 {
    font-family: "Avenir";
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2vw;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0% 0 0 0 ;
    line-height: 0;
}
.column-right-pic h2 {
    font-family: "Avenir";
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2vw;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0% 0 0 0 ;
    line-height: 1.7em;
}
.column-right-pic .button-ad {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: .8vw;
    width: 45%;
    height: 10%;
    padding: 0% 0 0 0 ;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    background-image: url(../Images/button-reserve.jpg);
    border:none;
}
.button-ad:hover {
    background-image: url(../Images/button-reserve-hover.jpg);
    cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;  
}
.button-ad:active {
    background-image: url(../Images/button-reserve-click.jpg)   
}
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('button-ad').onclick = function OpenInNewTab(url) {
  var win = window.open('http://www.example.org');
  win.focus();
}
```

Comment: but it works! see https://jsfiddle.net/8nwwt3ha/

Comment: Also you can remove onclick attribute from element in html, as you created Event Listener in JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mike, the problem is not the location of the button itself but the styles you are applying, yo can actually click the button, but you gave the button a 10% height, so you don't have enough area to click it, try removing the height property or at least give it a greater area to click, cheers

btw, it works fine in Chrome, but because Chrome treats the overflow "the text" as part of the button, Firefox and probably others don't

```
.column-right-pic .button-ad {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: .8vw;
    width: 45%;
    border-style: none;
    border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
    /*height: 10%;*/
    padding: 0% 0 0 0 ;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    background-image: url(../Images/button-reserve.jpg);
    /*background-color: #ff0000;*/
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: I'm using Firefox so that probably explains it! Let me try giving the button a bigger size to see if I can click it

Comment: really?, have a link??, I mean a demo, so the problem can be narrowed

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null ....well.... so then try to call your scripts at the bottom of the page, use the console is a great advise too, you are getting that error cuz you are calling an object that is not already loaded, nice design btw

Comment: Not sure what you mean by calling your scripts at the bottom of the page? can you show a jsfiddle by chance? Thanks for the positive comments.

Comment: I had the same problem when I tried to replicate your code, you have your script at the top of the page code, the button, in the middle, the code call that button and is not loaded yet, put the scripts before the end body tag

Comment: Ok, I'll add the script that contains the button JavaScript at the bottom of the page and see if that works. I left my laptop atm, but will try it when I get back. Did you try it and confirm it works?

Comment: yep, I did it the first time, use the console, so you can track the errors